# I am trying to change the text in a node in an xml document with jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, xml, post, text

I have an xml file that begins like so:

```
<employee id = "msarapin">
    <login>msarapin</login>
    <name>Marvin I Sarapin, Ph.D.</name>
    <title>Department Head</title>
    <position>Administration</position>
```

**I want to change the text inside the "name" node with jquery on click of a submit button.**

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('#submitUpdate').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "db.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml)
        {
            $(xml).find('employee[id$='+"<?php echo($_GET["id"]); ?>"+']').each(function(){
                $(this).find('name').each(function(){
                    $(this).text("New Name");
                    $.post('saveXml.php', { xml: $(xml)}, function(data){alert("Data Loaded: " + data);});
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my saveXml.php code:

```
<?php
$xml = $_POST['xml'];
$file = fopen("db.xml","w");
fwrite($file, $xml);
fclose($file);
echo "ok";?>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 18"  data: no]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, but I'm betting that the one that's tripping you up is

```
$.post('saveXml.php', { xml: $(xml) } ... );
```

It looks like you're expecting `$(xml)` to echo the XML as a string, but in fact it's a jQuery object, and your error is probably due to the fact that jQuery objects aren't serializable. You need to use `.html()`, and that means you need to wrap the XML object in another node, like this:

```
var xmlString = $('<div/>').append(xml).html();
$.post('saveXml.php', { xml: xmlString } ... );
```

The other problem, which is more a style question than an actual error, is your `.each()` loops. If you have multiple `<employee id="this_id">` nodes, or if that node has multiple `<name>` nodes, then you're calling `$.post()` more often than you need to. If there's only one of each of these nodes, then there's no need for the nested `.each()` methods. Either way, you can just select like this:

```
$(xml)
    .find('employee[id$='+"<?php echo($_GET["id"]); ?>"+']')
    .find('name')
    .text("New Name");
$.post( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the fast response. I can tell that it's posting and trying to write now, but I keep getting this error: **Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"  code: "3" nsresult: "0x80530003 (NS_ERROR_DOM_HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR)"  location: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js Line: 18"]**

Comment: Can you get any kind of stacktrace on the error? My guess is that it's a problem with the wrapper code: `$('<div/>').append(xml)` - but I'm not sure how to debug. You might try `dataType:"text"` and see if that fixes anything - jQuery might do some magic with `xml` data that prevents it from being appended to an HTML DOM element.